# Extracting positive elements from a matrix in R

Tags: r, select, matrix, extract

I have got this 6x6 matrix,

```
1    1    2    1    2    2
1    3    1    1    2    1
0    5    1    1    0    3
0    5    0    2    1    3
4    1    3    3    2    3
2    3    3    0    2    3
```

and I need to find a way to select all values >0 such that i can create a vector of all the elements bigger than 0. Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 5):

Assume `mat` is your matrix

```
mat[mat>0]
 [1] 1 1 4 2 1 3 5 5 1 3 2 1 1 3 3 1 1 1 2 3 2 2 1 2 2 2 1 3 3 3 3
```

Comment: Thanks, about 30 seconds after writing the question I figured it out myself after 2 hours of confusion.. turns out I had another file opened with similar variables which got me all confused.